# iOS charts value above bar font

Tags: ios-charts

I'm trying to set the font size and colour of the value above each bar on a bar chart with IOS charts. Can anyone help with this?

The label is shown but its small and dark.

[image]

Comment: You can make demo project and provide drive URL here, so anyone can download and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Well ,you can change it by use BarChartDataSet's properties.Such as:

```
/// Sets/get a single color for value text.
/// Setting the color clears the colors array and adds a single color.
/// Getting will return the first color in the array.
open var valueTextColor: NSUIColor

/// the font for the value-text labels
open var valueFont: NSUIFont
```

And do not forget to set `drawValuesEnabled` to true.